# Gas pressure within containers

Tags: pressure, temperature, ideal-gas

If, hypothetically, a gas had no inner pressure, and it was made to fill up a container.
If, then, the pressure within the container was increased by filling it up with yet more gas, until high pressure was achieved, this would, I assume, cause an increase in temperature.
After a period of time, temperature would drop and equalize with the environment. As I understand it, when temperature drops, so does pressure.
Why then do pressurized gas containers retain pressure, even though temperature has dropped ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: What do you mean by 'inner pressure'? If you have gas in a container, you have a pressure at any T > zero. If there is more gas, there is more pressure. You can vary that pressure by changing the temperature, but it won't go away (unless it leaks out).

Comment: That is because you will have more molecules inside after you add more gas.

Comment: @dmafa It seems like that should be an answer

Answer (score 1):

The Ideal Gas Law PV=nRT explains what happens. It can be written as PV/T=nR. For our purposes nR can be considered a constant, PV&T are all expressed in absolute units. Thus if the container volume is constant, P/T is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from volume and temperature, there is one more parameter affecting pressure, that is number of molecules. At filling up the container you added more molecules in, consequntly you get higher pressure.

Answer (score 0):

For commercial uses, usually these gases are in liquefied form .You can find more details, for LPG lets say , here:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquefied_petroleum_gas
In general you are right.